# Integration by substitution called Weierstrass substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have seen this recent question [What's wrong in my calculation of $\int_0^{3 \pi/4} \frac{\cos x}{1 + \cos x}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489619/whats-wrong-in-my-calculation-of-int-03-pi-4-frac-cos-x1-cos-xdx) and I have read that when I operate for integration by substitution this type has a name: **Weierstrass substitution**. But is it a name for a particular substitution or applies to any substitution?

I didn't know it was called a *Weierstrass substitution*.

**Addendum**: two screenshots from two different Italian math textbooks where they write **parametric formulas**.

*First image*

[image]

*Second image*

[image]

Comment: Weierstrass substitution means the tangent half-angle substitution. I.e., a particular kind of substitution. It doesn't mean integration by any substitution.

Comment: @down-voter(s) What is the reason of the downvote to my question? Is there an exact and clear reason?!!!!!!

Comment: Many books speak about Weierstrass substitution but this technique appears wall before by Euler (1707-1783) while Weierstrass (1815-1897).

Comment: @Sebastiano: I didn't downvote, but I suspect the reason would be “This question does not show any research effort”, since the answer can be found immediately with a simple Google search. For example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: @HansLundmark Hi, and thank you very much for further explanations. Now I put some screenshots taken from Italian textbooks. It is very simple to search on internet but it's not true that everything you read on the internet is always correct. I am not interesting for the downvote but for me it is very important to understand the reason.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hi, I really appreciate the clarification. I didn't know that at all. I thought it was a generic technique. Anyway, I also attached two images from two different Italian books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Weierstrass substitution is precisely

$$t = \tan \dfrac{x}{2},$$
so that 
$$\cos x = \dfrac{1 - t^2}{1 +  t^2}$$

$$\sin x = \dfrac{2t}{1 + t^2}$$
and
$$dx = \dfrac{2\,dt}{1+ t^2}.$$

It rationalizes the expressions that contain trigonometric functions.

For example,

$$\int\frac{\cos x}{\cos x+1}dx=\int\frac{\dfrac{1 - t^2}{1 +  t^2}}{\dfrac{1 - t^2}{1 +  t^2}+1}\frac{2\,dt}{t^2+1}=\int\dfrac{1 - t^2}{1 +  t^2}dt.$$

---

Note that Weierstrass is also useful to find the roots of trigonometric polynomials.

E.g. with the classical linear equation

$$a\cos x+b\sin x+c=0$$ we obtain

$$a(1-t^2)+2bt=c(1+t^2),$$

which is quadratic.

Comment: I call them parametric equations. when I teach goniometry to my students. But I didn't know it was called Weierstrass.

Comment: @Sebastiano: "parametric equations" is a quite generic term and does not echo a substitution of a single variable. If I were you I would avoid it.

Comment: I'll take your advice. In school textbooks they write "parametric equations in function of $t=\tan(x/2)$".

Comment: @Sebastiano: they are probably referring to the fact that $(\cos x,\sin x)$ describes a circle and the Weierstrass substitution provides its parametric equations in a rational form. But this is indirect.

Comment: I accepted your answer and I really appreciate it. I don't appreciate unjustified negative votes. Thank you always very much and best wishes.

Comment: @Sebastiano: there's nothing I can do about these :-)

Comment: Something is missing...the polynomial should be equal to zero.